# How should I change to svn protocol instead of http

Tags: svn, svn-server

My current path of svn server is

**http://file/repo/test**

but I want use svn protocol instead of http

**svn://file/repo/test** to do a SVN sync

what I need to do.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion's default protocol is the svn. http protocol is extented by apache to subversion.
You have two options:

1- You can re-fetch whole project by `svn co snv://blahblah.net/blah_project blah_project_2` near to old one and continue on new one..

2- You can change server adres by svn command: `svn switch --relocate http://blahblah.net/blah_project svn://blahblah.net/blah_project`

Comment: i have tried with following command: svn switch --relocate http://blahblah.net/blah_project svn://blahblah.net/blah_project but it is giving error : no working copy

Comment: Did you give the command in project root folder?